# Visual Studio for mac iOS storyboard not working

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, storyboard, xamarin-studio

I'm using **Visual Studio for mac** for my Xamarin project. and also I'm using Xamarin Studio, because of few bugs.

I tried to edit iOS Package's Launchscreen.storyboard file, but it didn't work. It says "The designer could not be initialized.". and [Error messages are too long... ;-;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnkvK.jpg)

So I edited it on Xcode. I added Background Color and app's logo but after I built it, but the logo didn't came out.

Comment: Cyan, What are the VS and Xcode versions? Take a look at this bulletin. https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-xcode-8-3-support-for-vs-2017/ . I'm having the same problem but I'm using Xamarin Studio to edit my storyboard files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing storyboards in `Visual Studio for Mac` is not the only way to do it. VS for Mac is still in preview.

You can use Xamarin Studio side by side with VS for Mac. So you can edit storyboards in XS instead of VS for Mac.

Alternatively (and this is my personal preference) you can edit storyboards in XCode by using context menu on the storyboard file in Solution Explorer and choosing *Open with* -> *XCode*.

Here is a plugin for Xamarin Studio to open storyboards by default in XCode: https://github.com/colbylwilliams/DefaultDesigner

There is a video showing how to use XCode with Xamarin (start from [14:34](https://youtu.be/RnW7m0acxg0?t=876))

Comment: Thank you! I re-installed Xamarin.iOS, and It fixed but only working on Xamarin Studio, not on VS for mac. anyway, I can edit .storyboard file. :)